# Issue raising an error in after trigger

Tags: error-handling, triggers, salesforce

I'm having an issue raising an error in an after trigger, and I don't see any reason why I can raise an error one way, but not the other. Let me give you an example.

The following trigger will fail and raise the following error:

> Error:Apex trigger tstTrigger2 caused an unexpected exception, contact
>   your administrator: tstTrigger2 : execution of AfterUpdate caused by:
>   System.FinalException: SObject row does not allow errors:
>   Trigger.tstTrigger2 : line 19, column 1

```
trigger tstTrigger2 on Account (after update) 
{  


    Set<Id> AccountIds = Trigger.newMap.keySet();


    List<Account > accountsToProcess = [Select Id, Name from Account Where Id IN : AccountIds];


    for(Account act: accountsToProcess)
    {

        act.addError('doesn't work');

    }    

}
```

However, raising an error this way works. Please note there is always ever only 1 record in the keyset, at least in this test scenario.

```
trigger tstTrigger on Account (after update) 
{  


    Set<Id> AccountIds = Trigger.newMap.keySet();


    List<Account > accountsToProcess = [Select Id, Name from Account Where Id IN : AccountIds];


    Trigger.new[0].addError('However, this works?');

}
```

Any explanation of why the first one is failing, and the second one is not is greatly appreciated. As well, if you could point me to the best way to implement this so that it's bulkified that would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

addError() doesn't roll back your insertion it will just prevent the further execution of the script, so the data is never inserted if an you throw an error on UI.

By doing  this

```
Trigger.new[0].addError('However, this works?');
```

You're simply throwing an error on the first record in the list thereby stopping anything processing.

Something like this will solve your first code snip

```
trigger tstTrigger2 on Account (after update) 
{
   Map<ID, Account> accountMap = Trigger.newMap;

   for(ID act: accountMap.keySet())
   {
      accountMap.get(act).addError('doesnt work');
   }   
}
```

You were querying out the account Ids and by that time they were already committed to the database, which won't allow errors to be flagged on the records

Comment: I'm not trying to roll back any insertions, this is strictly to raise an error and stop execution of the script. Sorry, I don't think I'm quite understanding quite yet. What about your script allows this to work vs mine. Isn't your 'accountmap.get' function simply returning one account to apply the error to? I assume this would be the exact same thing that the loop I included would do. Thanks!

Comment: .addError can be called on Trigger.new in before/after insert and before/after update triggers, and on Trigger.old in before delete List. You can't add this to any other sObject that is why error is saying SObject row does not allow error.  This is a hard example because no matter what your failing every single account you update, I thought you were just testing things out, I really don't know what your trying to do

Comment: I think that is where the confusion lies here. I see this error telling me that I'm not allowed to update any other sObject, but I'm only trying to update one sObject. I'm assuming this is referring to a different Account record, but maybe this is referring to a different sObject in the sense of trying to update an account rather than a trigger (map?)? THAT makes more sense to me. Am I on the right path? :)

Comment: Yup, obviously you would actually have some qualifying if statements in the for loop because you wouldn't want to fail every account that is updated

Comment: Actually maybe this is the issue. Does the trigger differentiate between the items being processes in the trigger and the records returned from the SOQL query? To me at least, they are the same records, but maybe that is a distinction that is causing the confusion on my end and the error?

Comment: Good point you were querying out records that were actually already inserted and then trying to put errors on those records, I didn't even think about that.  They are essentially the same records, just currently (kinda) in a different context, you can't do that..

Comment: @tchock Are we good? is this answer good enough to get closed?